Something changed with ubuntu 20, 22, 24 that is affecting base cpu speed clock on intel 13900k
I have been having a problem since upgrading my system from ubuntu 20 to 22 & 24.  The base cpu clock is running extremely slow on ubuntu 22 and 24.
When on ubuntu 20 my base cpu clock is around 2.5 to 3.0 ghz.
When on ubuntu 22 and 24 my base cpu clock is around .9-1.3 ghz which causes the system to lag and hang up when doing minimal tasks.
What changed between the versions?




Which command line tool is it in the outputs? I'm no expert but I'd check (or fiddle with) the so called performance option selected in the performance menu which is accessible through the power icon on that desktop bar with the clock and all, and equally accessible in the settings "power" menu, of Ubuntu 22.04 at least.

Your screen shots do not provide evidence of an issue. The CPU is rather idle in all of them, and it is normal for the CPU frequency to scale down in that situation. Put one or more CPUs under a heavy load and then look at the CPU frequencies.

If you want to read what changed; why not read the list of things changed that is provided along with release notes on each release?  (*this is also provided for point releases too)  Why ask us for what is provided, did you read the lists?  Don't forget LTS releases have kernel stack choice too, so 20.04 with HWE is using the identical software stack as 22.04 when GA stack is used; so there is more involved than just release... so consider everything including choices you made with your installs (you don't specify anything beyond release details; not giving choices you made)
